# What does high CPU load in htop for processes with status S mean?

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, process, htop

When monitoring my system with `htop`, the process status column for most processes under load is mostly `S` and switches to `R` sometimes. From my understanding of the docs status `S` means that a process is sleeping, while for `R` it is running. But how can a sleeping process consume the CPU as much as I can see in the screenshot underneath? I would have expected a load of `0` most of the time for those processes.

I suspect to have an `I/O` bottleneck, so quite some sleeping processes waiting for `I/O` would make sense. But in such a case I don't understand the high CPU load for sleeping processes. Might that be the result of e.g. many context switches, because `I/O` is unable to provide a reasonable throughput, but is offering very few data quite often? That would mean the CPUs couldn't be used otherwise while waiting for all `I/O` to succeed.

Or might it only be a display issue, because waiting for `I/O` needs to be displayed somehow and it is in terms of load, but actually those processes don't consume any CPU? In such a case the CPUs would be used as needed to really process things.

Thanks for any insight!

[image: htop]

Comment: CPU consumption is reported over a time period, 'S' is the status at the end of that time. Processes can change between run and sleep all the time (sleeping to wait for the hard disk to read those bytes).

Comment: When a program has a high CPU consumption it is difficult for other processes to get a chance to run. I suspect that `htop` is most likely to get its CPU time during the rare occasions when the high-CPU programs are waiting for something (disc, swap, network, semaphore, etc).

Comment: @AFH Except `R` means ready to run, not necessarily actually using the CPU at that moment.

Comment: @Aganju Waiting for disk I/O would be indicated by `D`, not `S`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I realised that: on a single-core system it must mean mean ready to run, as `htop` is using the only CPU, and this will happen only as a result of time-slicing, though I've not looked at the details of this algorithm on Linux. As far as `S` and `D` are concerned, you are right, and I shouldn't have included disc accesses in my list of wait states, though in theory a disc driver could be written to allow interrupt handling, in which case `S` would show - but the standard hard and network disc drivers on Ubuntu have not been written that way.

Comment: Its also notable that htop's refresh-rate is 1 Second (at least by default) so it will have to do some gymnastics in order to show states and time when time-slicing between threads which happens on an 10-100 ms time scale. there may have been 1/10/100 threads that got time during that last second.