# Does htop have a bug in the display of process status and memory consumption?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, htop, bug

When running a few processes, I noticed that `htop` showed certain process as consuming CPU, but yet were marked `S` in the State column (the `S` column)...which meant that the processes were sleeping or idle, but I know they were not sleeping. They were actively running. Also, in the `VIRT` memory consumption, it shows `48.6G`. Surely, it could not be 48.6 gigabytes. Is this some bug in `htop`? I've seen the `man` page, but is there some other source of info where these abbreviations and explanations are provided in more detail?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that htop showed certain process as consuming CPU, but yet were marked S in the State column (the S column)...which meant that the processes were sleeping or idle, but I know they were not sleeping. They were actively running

They cannot *all* be running at the same time – only one task per CPU core can truly "run", while the rest have to wait until the scheduler gets to them. (So e.g. on a single-core CPU, htop would only be able to see *itself* as running...)

But I *think* the real problem is that htop doesn't actually have the ability to get an "instant" snapshot of the entire system state (at least not on Linux). Instead it must read the status of each process *one at a time* – which itself takes some CPU time, and during that time other processes may be rescheduled, and the scan may actually miss the running process.

(For example, while htop is reading /proc/12345/status, it might say "Status: S" because it's sleeping while process 23456 is running... but once htop reaches /proc/23456, that too might say "Status: S" because by that time, 23456 has been paused and 12345 is the one that's running, so the end result is that both processes are shown as sleeping even though both were "running".)

Though it is also possible that Linux itself (i.e. the kernel) doesn't always report the state as "running" accurately (for various reasons, again most likely related to timing).

> Also, in the VIRT memory consumption, it shows 48.6G. Surely, it could not be 48.6 gigabytes

It can, because `VIRT` *is not memory consumption* – it's address space consumption, and the address space can be mapped to many other things besides physical RAM (or swap). The actual "memory consumption" is the `RSS` column.

(As one example, it is possible to map *files* directly into the address space – mapping a whole 10GB file would appear to "consume" 10GB in the VIRT column even though it consumes barely any physical RAM. As another example, some web browsers allocate huge "guard" mappings to isolate JavaScript from the rest; most of the mapping remains empty and therefore doesn't consume any RAM either.)

However, htop *does not* actually show 48.8G in your screenshot. All but one "ffmpeg" items in this list are *threads* (colored in green), and all threads within a process share the same memory – so it's 797M RSS (and 1847M virtual address space) for the entire ffmpeg process regardless of how many threads it has. (Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide threads.)

Answer (score 2):

`S` means *interruptible sleep* (waiting for an event to complete).
CPU consumption is reported over a time period, and 'S' may be the
status at the end of that time. Processes can change between
Running and Sleep all the time
(such as sleeping to wait for the hard disk to read bytes).

When a program has a high CPU consumption it is difficult for other
processes to get a chance to run on the same CPU core.
On a computer with few cores, `htop` might be most likely to get its
CPU time when the high-CPU programs are waiting for something
(disc, swap, network, semaphore, etc).

Its also notable that htop's refresh-rate is 1 second (by default),
so it will have to do some gymnastics in order to show states and
time, when time-slicing between threads is happening on a
10-100 ms time scale.
There might have been 1/10/100 threads that got time during that last second.

The conclusion from all this is that the display by `htop` is only a
summary of what has been going on in the computer in the last second,
not a precise list or snapshot of the computer's state at some
exact instant.

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/1186902/what-does-high-cpu-load-in-htop-for-processes-with-status-s-mean)